# How to hide labels in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code which depends on this javascript from dynamic drive:
http://dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex16/formdependency.htm
Its a form dependency manager. Which will show or hide elements depending on what you choose from the forms that are revealed:

I don't know why but If I alter the code from this:

```
<td>
       <label>ID Number<input type="checkbox" name="id" class="DEPENDS ON info BEING student"></label>
           </td>
        </tr>
```

To this:

```
    <td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="id" class="DEPENDS ON info BEING student"><label>ID Number</label>
       </td>
    </tr>
```

Note: The only change that I did here is to transfer the label from the left side of the checkbox to the right side so that they will look better.
But when I do this. The labels will be visible even if I did not yet click on the button that will make it visible(but without the checkboxes).

And when I click on that button, that's the only time when the checkbox will appear on the left side of the labels.

The checkbox is ok, but the label is not. And the javascript is working properly.
What do I do so that the checkbox and label will go together?

Comment: need to clarify your example. It looks like you did a lost more than 'transfer the label from the left side of the checkbox to the right.'

Comment: that's just an example, I edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is to leave the `<label>` tag in front of the `<input>` tag and just move the text to the right of it:

```
<td>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="id" class="DEPENDS ON info BEING student">ID Number</label>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Or you can use SLaks answer and add an `id` attribute to the `<input>` tag and a matching `for` attribute to the `<label>` tag like so (so that the text toggles the checkbox):

```
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="id" class="DEPENDS ON info BEING student" id="example"><label for="example" class="DEPENDS ON info BEING student">ID Number</label>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I still see the label ID number when I use this

Comment: @user225269: Incorporating SLaks answer into my solution should fix the problem.  I think the solution I just added is simpler and should work as well.

Comment: I think this is the simplest solution to this problem, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on the **[W3 documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html)** to assign a label to an input you have tofollow this instruction

```
 <FORM action="..." method="post">
 <P>
      <LABEL>
         First Name
         <INPUT type="text" name="firstname">
      </LABEL>
      <LABEL>
         <INPUT type="text" name="lastname">
         Last Name
      </LABEL>
 </P>
 </FORM>
```

following text included in that article

> To associate a label with another control implicitly, the control element must be within the contents of the LABEL element. In this case, the LABEL may only contain one control element. The label itself may be positioned before or after the associated control.
>
> Note that this technique cannot be used when a table is being used for layout, with the label in one cell and its associated control in another cell.
>
> When a LABEL element receives focus, it passes the focus on to its associated control. See the section below on access keys for examples.
>
> Labels may be rendered by user agents in a number of ways (e.g., visually, read by speech synthesizers, etc.)

So you have to follow the instruction, was it clear or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `class="DEPENDS ON info BEING student"` to the `<label>`.

Comment: This will not actually associate the label to the checkbox, so that clicking the label also toggles the checkbox.

Comment: @trey: Obviously, the `for` attribute should also be used correctly.  However, that doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that form dependency script expects HTML in the form

```
<label>ID Number<input type="checkbox" name="id" class="DEPENDS ON info BEING student"></label>
```

and doesn't handle any other cases.

If you add `id` attributes to your inputs and `for` attributes to your labels:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="id" "name="id" class="DEPENDS ON info BEING student"><label for="id">ID Number</label>
```

and in FormManager.js add this to the end of `showEl()` and `hideEl()` (inside `setupDependencies()`):

```
var id = this.id, labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label'), l = labels.length, label, i;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    label = labels[i];
    if (label.htmlFor == id) {
        label.style.display = 'none'; // 'none' for hideEl, '' for showEl
    }
}
```

it should work.